Is this the correct use-case for MS Dynamics Power Apps Components?
My company provides a B2B SaaS product, which is used by sales teams. We offer "plugins" which our customers can install in their CRM/Sales system, such as Hubspot and Salesforce. The plugin is embedded in their sales tool, directly in the, e.g., contact, lead or deal view. The plugin provides a way to interact with our SaaS tool, but directly from their own CRM interface.
Now we would like to offer a plugin for customers that use Microsoft Dynamics 365 Sales. From my initial investigation, it seems that their Power Apps Component Framework is used for this purpose. Is this right?
If so, how does a customer install a component? Do they do that from some Microsoft Power Apps marketplace, or can we do that programmatically for them?
Is the component able to make HTTPS requests to our API?
